# Android localhost url is not working for tomcat 7

Tags: android, eclipse, jakarta-ee, tomcat7, android-webservice

I am using `tomcat 7` from Java EE eclipse i also made a code for server part. In android i also made a project and ran it and using HttPGet of server part Url but my getRequest is not working.

My server is working in that Url

```
http://localhost:8080/dhoom/index.jsp
```

And in my android project i used like this:

```
String URL = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/dhoom/index.jsp";

HttpClient user = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(URL);
```

`getRequest` is not working need help thanks in advance.

Comment: Is ip10.0.2.2 is valid ip for your tomcat server?

Comment: Android app is running on emulator or device?

Comment: Noor Nawaz sir,
I am running on device

Comment: Miya G, how could i know 10.0.2.2 valid or not? :(

Comment: Then access it through system IP like 192.168.1.10:8080, Because your server is not localhost host for device. it only localhost for  emulator

Comment: Noor Nawaz sir not working with
192.168.1.10:8080

Comment: write down your pc name if u don't know your IP. I supposed that your ip is 192.168.1.10

Comment: Which Os are u using?

Comment: @noor nawaz.... Why are you trying blind answers?

Comment: Miya G, i am using windows 8.1

Comment: Okay Now open your system's command prompt and run ipconfig commang on prompt you will find your local ip here. If you are trying to access web application on lan then use above ip with http port that should be ip:8080

Answer (score 0):

Open your system's command prompt and run ipconfig command on prompt, you will find your local/public ip here this ip will depend upon your internet connectivity . If you are trying to access web application on lan then use above local ip with http port that should be ip:8080.

If you want to use on wan then you have to a static IP to access web application in your mobile application.